# CSS Align logo same height as text

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-position, text-align

How can I align the logo and the text link next to it on the same height? Is this something done with `display: inline-block;` ?

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  
  <a href="google.be"><img alt="logo" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/5/51/Wikimedia_logo.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/50?cb=20100313090805"> wikipedia</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: A demonstration of an `inline-block` solution would be: `nav * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}` - but I would suggest applying a better html structure so that the global selector `*` wouldn't be necessary to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use flexbox, as noted in another answer. You can also use the `vertical-align` property

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <a href="google.be"><img alt="logo" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/5/51/Wikimedia_logo.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/50?cb=20100313090805"> wikipedia</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm already working with CSS Grids so I prefer to keep to that instead of mixing it with a little bit of flexbox

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Flexbox` and set `align-items: center`.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="google.be"><img alt="logo" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/5/51/Wikimedia_logo.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/50?cb=20100313090805"> wikipedia</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

just simple add `vertical-align:middle;` on image

```css
img{
vertical-align:middle;
margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="google.be"><img alt="logo" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/5/51/Wikimedia_logo.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/50?cb=20100313090805"> wikipedia</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: blue;
   }

    img{
    position:absolute;
    }
    span{
    position:relative;
    top:16px;
    left:50px;
    }

    <!-- language: lang-html -->

        <nav>

          <a href="google.be"><img alt="logo" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/5/51/Wikimedia_logo.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/50?cb=20100313090805"> <span>wikipedia</span></a>
        </nav>

    <!-- end snippet -->
```